# RTCReporting & pancake.apple.com errors

Tags: ios, avplayer

Yesterday I updated Xcode to Version 5.1 (5B130a); the simulator's version now reads Version 7.1 (463.9.41).

Today I started getting these weird errors when beginning playback using AVPlayer. I have never seen any such errors in the past, can't find any info about them, and have no idea what they mean. They are not fatal and I haven't noticed any ill effects from them. But…

What is RTCReporting and how did it get into my project?

What does pancake.apple.com have to do with anything?

Etc. Thanks.

```
2014-03-21 16:16:34.129 0.1[3330:5403] RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
2014-03-21 16:17:17.201 0.1[3330:5403] RTCReporting(getSvrConfig): error resolving with lookup server http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
2014-03-21 16:17:17.201 0.1[3330:5403] RTCReporting(getSvrConfig): sendSynchronousRequest error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x10f110d60 {NSUnderlyingError=0x11230ed80 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
2014-03-21 16:17:17.202 0.1[3330:5403] RTCReporting: can't get storebag from the server
```

---

UPDATE: I had not previously noticed any harm from this, but now my app is hanging (in simulator) for about 5 seconds while I'm just getting an item ready for playback (before I've pressed play). Here's what the debug navigator shows if I press pause during the hang:

[image]

When the app unfreezes after 5 seconds, just the following is logged:

```
RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
```

**A note on "answers":**

I'm looking for non-obvious explanation related to the questions I posed.

Comment: I was also pretty confused with the pancake.apple.com warning LOL

Answer (score 44):

This seems to be a problem with trying to play videos on the simulator.  I've had this problem for months now, and just ran into it again today when I was trying to play video on my simulator.

The solution, while not great, is to use an actual device instead of the simulator for testing video playing.

Comment: Thx Will, that saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I'm getting the same issue when playing back an audio stream using AVPlayer in the simulator.

Answer (score 24):

I always encounter this issue if I've got an Exception Breakpoint enabled when I play a video. If I disable it then it works fine. I've submitted a bug report to Apple also.

Comment: Is this issue solved? I am facing it when i stream song from native MPMoviePlayer..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with trying to play videos on the simulator.
I solved by quiting other audio or video playing from my system.

Answer (score -8):

You need use:

```
[player play];
```

after you sound play in the real device and in simulator.