# Streaming from Wowza to an iOS app using playlist.m3u8

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm using Wowza media server and stream an On-Demand MP3. When I stream the url directly from Safari - it plays just fine. When I try to use `AVPlayer` it just doesn't work. The code is:

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.23:1935/vod/mp3:hot160.mp3/playlist.m3u8"))
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)    
player.play()
```

Excuse the code, it's actually `Swift` instead of `Objective-C` but the concept is just the same. It doesn't play at all and I get a console message:

```
RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=5.9
```

I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've seen this issue upon trying to playback via the simulator vs. on an actual device.  Similar to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569013/rtcreporting-pancake-apple-com-errors)